# How would I position a button in the top left of a textarea in html?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I position a button in the top left of a second textarea?

Here is an example of what I want to do:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d14uB.png)

Comment: Q: How would I position a button ... in html? A: 1) Read about CSS and CSS layouts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/, etc. etc. 2) Consider using a framework like Bootstrap

Comment: This couldnt be more unhelpful

Comment: Your example confuses me right now. What is different there?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button>blah</button>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```